# Timber: Exclude category method

Tags: wordpress, timber

I wish to exclude some categories from my output using the statement below but only the first argument '1' is honoured.

Can anyone determine why the following arguments are not also excluded (the id's are correct, if i change the order the first id is always excluded):

```
$context['categories'] = Timber::get_terms('category', array( 'exclude' =>  14, 13, 1));
```

These didn't work either

```
$context['categories'] = Timber::get_terms('category=-1,-13,-14');

$context['categories'] = Timber::get_terms('cat=-1,-13,-14');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second two lines of code will never work according to my knowledge because wordpress do not accepting the negative value in exclude parameter. Negative value is taken in only post_per_page only.

Try below code if you are not using custom taxonomy :

```
$context['categories'] = Timber::get_terms('cat', array( 'hide_empty' => 1,'exclude' =>  1));
```

If you are using the custom taxonomy than it will be something like below you need to change the slug only

```
$context['categories'] = Timber::get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' =>0));
```

Comment: Hi Aki, thanks for your quick reply! It was late when I posted so I have edited the post to give my question a better context. Thanks again for your help. Dave

Comment: Hi Aki, no it didn't resolve  he issue I'm afraid. I have updated my question to give more details. Thanks.

Comment: I missed out 'hide_empty' => 1' This is what worked in the end. $context['categories'] = Timber::get_terms('category', array('hide_empty' => 1,'exclude' => 14, 13, 1));